# Unable to resolve module `./index.css` from `node_modules\antd-mobile\lib\button \style\css.js`

Tags: react-native, babeljs, antd-mobile, expo

When I am running this command:

```
expo build:android
```

I am getting following errors:

```
Unable to resolve module `./index.css` from `node_modules\antd-mobile\lib\button\style\css.js`:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\antd-mobile\lib\button\style\index.css(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.na
tive.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.nat
ive.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts
|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|
.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * node_modules\antd-mobile\lib\button\style\index.css\index(.native|.ios.expo.
ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.j
s|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.nat
ive.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx
|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
Packager URL http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules\expo\AppEntry.bundle?dev=false&
minify=true&hot=false&platform=ios returned unexpected code 500. Please open you
r project in the Expo app and see if there are any errors. Also scroll up and ma
ke sure there were no errors or warnings when opening your project.
```

I have already done following:

```
npm cache verify
expo -r c
```

`package.json` file is as given below:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
    "antd-mobile": "^2.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "rc-form": "^2.4.11",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.12",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

`babel.config.js` is as given below:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
        plugins: [
            [
                "import",{ libraryName: "antd-mobile", style: "css" }
            ]
        ]
    };
};
```

Comment: Just a hunch but is this not due to antd-mobile being a react (web) package and React Native unable to handle HTML/CSS code. Would using https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-mobile-rn not make more sense?

Comment: @P.Brew Yes, using ant-mobile-rn package will be good alternative as this error is not present there.